# How to write mysql innerquery when get the records count from same table

Tags: mysql, join, count, inner-join, average

Query to get results from 2 tables:

```
SELECT path.* FROM (SELECT  tbc.course_name
slp.course_id,slp.student_type,slp.stu_reference_id,
count(slp.course_id) as counttotalWatchedStudents
 from tbl_student_learning_path  slp LEFT JOIN tbl_courses tbc
 on tbc.course_pid = slp.course_id WHERE slp.stu_reference_id =34 
and slp.student_type='institute' GROUP BY slp.course_id ) as path
```

Query result table:

```
| course_id                     | totalCollegeStudents | fullwatchedStudentsCount | counttotalWatchedStudents | sumOfWatchPointsForWatchedStudents | totalStudentsAvg | fullwatchedAvg |
|-------------------------------|----------------------|--------------------------|---------------------------|------------------------------------|------------------|----------------|
| Number Systems                | 9                    | 0                        | 3                         | 60                                 | 20.0000          | 0              |
| Percentages                   | 9                    | 0                        | 3                         | 30                                 | 10.0000          | 0              |
| Blood Relations               | 9                    | 3                        | 3                         | 300                                | 100.0000         | 300            |
| Calandar                      | 9                    | 3                        | 3                         | 300                                | 100.0000         | 300            |
| Percentages                   | 9                    | 3                        | 3                         | 300                                | 100.0000         | 300            |
| Permutation &amp; Combination | 9                    | 3                        | 3                         | 300                                | 100.0000         | 300            |
| Probability                   | 9                    | 0                        | 3                         | 90                                 | 30.0000          | 0              |
| Ratios                        | 9                    | 0                        | 3                         | 120                                | 40.0000          | 0              |
| Time and Work                 | 9                    | 0                        | 3                         | 150                                | 50.0000          | 0              |
| Time Speed &amp; Distance     | 9                    | 1                        | 3                         | 140                                | 46.6667          | 100            |
| Averages                      | 9                    | 3                        | 3                         | 300                                | 100.0000         | 300            |
| Coding and Decoding           | 9                    | 3                        | 3                         | 300                                | 100.0000         | 300            |
```

From the above table, i want to add inner query to the main query 
query should be something like this:

```
( select count(t1.watched_percentage) from tbl_student_learning_path t1 
WHERE t1.stu_reference_id =34 and t1.student_type='institute' 
AND t1.watched_percentage >= 90 group by t1.course_id  )
fullwatchedStudentsCount,
```

And the result should come like this(this is nothing but if first table counttotalWatchedStudents value is 3 it means that there are 2 type of people
1.students watched full (watched_percentage>=90)
2.students still watching (watched_percentage 1-89)
 )

```
| fullwatchedStudentsCount | fullwatchedStudentsSum |
|--------------------------|------------------------|
| 2                        | 200                    |
| 1                        | 100                    |
| 0                        | 0                      |
| 2                        | 200                    |
| 1                        | 100                    |
| 1                        | 100                    |
| 0                        | 0                      |
| 2                        | 200                    |
| 2                        | 200                    |
| 1                        | 100                    |
| 2                        | 200                    |
| 1                        | 100                    |
```

Comment: This looks strange. You group by `slp.course_id` and display `slp.student_type` and `slp.stu_reference_id`. Can't there be different student types and reference IDs per course? Don't you care which you display?

Comment: Actually sorry i dont needed that column `student_type` it is for where condition. No only one student type will come because if you see where condtion we are calling only `student_type='institue'` and `stu_reference_id=34`.

Comment: Ah, you are right; I overlooked that.

Comment: I don't know what column you are adding up, but maybe you are looking for something like this: `sum(case when slp.watched_percentage >= 90 then value else 0 end)`. Where `value`is the column name in question.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner let me explain if you see the column `sumOfWatchPointsForWatchedStudents ` in that sum of `watched_percentag` is coming. i.e from all students ex:`3`........ similarly i want to get sum of students who watched more than `90` ex: `1` stud watched `90%` and second student watched is `100%` then the sum of fullwatchedstudents is `190`  how can i get this data..?  understood.?

Comment: So the column you want to add up is `slp.watched_percentage`. As mentioned you must replace `value` with the column name in the expression I've just shown. Hence `sum(case when slp.watched_percentage >= 90 then slp.watched_percentage else 0 end)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want sum up the students which saw more than 90% in another column:

I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT tbc.course_name,
       slp.course_id,
       slp.student_type,
       slp.stu_reference_id,
       count(slp.course_id) AS counttotalWatchedStudents,
       sum(if(slp.watched_percentage>=90, 1, 0)) AS fullwatchedStudentsCount
       sum(if(slp.watched_percentage>=90, watched_percentage, 0)) AS fullwatchedStudentsSum
FROM tbl_student_learning_path slp
LEFT JOIN tbl_courses tbc ON tbc.course_pid = slp.course_id
WHERE slp.stu_reference_id =34
    AND slp.student_type='institute'
GROUP BY slp.course_id
enter code here
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can you please check my update table last column i want that result, it is nothing but the sum but with sum we are getting students count then how can we get the sum of watched_paercentage for only selected students...?

Comment: I changed my query and added the `fullwatchedStudentsSum`

Comment: @ it is working but can you please explain  the behaviour..?

Comment: if you read the query carefully you can actually figure it out.
It works like this:
For each row *if* watched_percentage bigger or equal 90 then add watched_percentage to the sum else add 0 to the sum.

Comment: Yeah now i understood thank you somuch for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.
Maybe also have a look here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html
there you can find some more examples.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to count students with a `watched_percentage >= 90`? Use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT 
  tbc.course_name,
  slp.course_id,
  slp.student_type,
  slp.stu_reference_id,
  COUNT(*) as counttotalWatchedStudents,
  SUM(slp.watched_percentage >= 90) as fullwatchedStudentsCount,
  SUM(slp.watched_percentage < 90) as stillwatchedStudentsCount
FROM tbl_student_learning_path slp 
LEFT JOIN tbl_courses tbc ON tbc.course_pid = slp.course_id
WHERE slp.stu_reference_id = 34 
  AND slp.student_type= 'institute' 
GROUP BY slp.course_id;
```

MySQL treats true = 1 and false = 0, so you can simply sum the trues :-)

Comment: Nice solution, didn't know you can omit the if statement :)

Comment: Yes, but aside from this my answer is the same as yours. I didn't see yours when I posted mine.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis  can you please check my update table last column i want that result, it is nothing but the sum but with sum we are getting students count then how can we get the sum of watched_paercentage for only selected students...?